# In Lua, how to get the tail of an array without copying it?

Tags: lua

I'm wokring with Lua 5.2, and for the sake of this question, assume that the tables are used exclusively as arrays.

Here's a function that returns the *tail* of an array (the array minus its first element):

```
function tail(t)

   if # t <= 1 then
      return nil
   end

   local newtable = {}
   for i, v in ipairs(t) do
      if i > 1 then
          table.insert(newtable, v)
      end
   end

   return newtable
end
```

For instance:

> prompt> table.concat(tail({10, 23, 8}), ", ")
>
> 23, 8

However this is achieved by returning a new copy of the table. Is there a way to avoid the creation of a new table?

I am looking for the equivalent of C's returning a pointer to the next element (`t++`). Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already explained, this is normally impossible.

However, using metatables, you *could* implement a `tail` function that performs what you want without copying all the data, by *referencing* the original table. The following works for most operations in Lua 5.2, but for example not for `table.concat`:

```
function tail(t)
  return setmetatable({}, {
    __index = function(_, k) return t[k+1] end,
    __newindex = function(_, k, v) t[k+1] = v end,
    __len = function(_) return #t-1 end,
    __ipairs = function(_) return 
      function(_, i)
        if i+1==#t then return nil end
        return i+1, t[i+2] end, 
      t, 0 end,
    __pairs = function(t) return ipairs(t) end,
  })
end
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the nicest way I know to implement tail(). It makes one new table, but I don't think that's avoidable.

```
function tail(list)
    return { select(2, unpack(list)) }
end
```

Comment: This is subject to lua's stack limit if the list is large, for what it is worth. The comments here suggest that it is around 1000 or so:

https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/678

Answer (score 3):

Nicol is correct that you can't reference a slice of an array, but there is an easier/shorter way to do what you want to do:

```
function tail(t)
  local function helper(head, ...) return #{...} > 0 and {...} or nil end
  return helper((table.unpack or unpack)(t))
end
```

`print(table.concat(tail({10, 23, 8}), ", "))` will then print `23,8`.

(added `table.unpack or unpack` to make it also work with Lua 5.2)

Comment: Wow, nice one. Question: Is it generally considered good practice in Lua to use boolean logic (`and` `or`) for conditional branching? I know some languages frown upon this.

Comment: @rahmu: It's legal Lua code. Whether it's "good practice" is a matter of opinion and debate.

Comment: This code is interesting, but has a limitation in terms of array size. The number of arguments that can be passed to a function is limited in Lua, typically at 2000.

Comment: This and..or trick is in PiL, which I guess means it is idiomatic Lua.

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for the equivalent of C's returning a pointer to the next element (t++). Is it possible?

No. The only *possible* reason you could want this is performance. Such a feature is only found in low-level programming languages. Lua is a scripting language: performance is not such a priority that this would be implemented.

Just make another table like you're doing, or use `table.remove` to modify the original. Whichever works best for you. Remember: the big, important objects like tables and userdata are all stored by reference in Lua, not by value.

Answer (score 1):

prapin's suggestion, to use metatables to present a view of the sequence, is roughly the way I'd do it.  An abstraction that might help is defining a metatable for *segments*, which can be an 0-ary function that returns a pair of a table and an offset index - we are only using functions here to represent tuples.  We can then define a metatable that makes this function behave like a table:

```
do
  local tail_mt = {
    __index = function(f, k) local t, i=f(); return t[k+i] end,
    __newindex = function(f, k, v) local t,i=f(); t[k+1] = v end,
    __len = function(f) local t,i=f(); return #t-i end,
    __ipairs = function(f) 
      local t,i = f () 
      return
        function (_, j)
          if i+j>=#t then 
            return nil
          else
            return j+1, t[i+j+1] 
          end
        end, nil, 0 
      end,
  }
  tail_mt.__pairs = tail_mt.__ipairs -- prapin collapsed this functionality, so I do too

  function tail (t)
    if type(t) == "table" then
      return setmetatable ( function () return t, 1 end, tail_mt )
    elseif type(t) == "function" then
      local t1, i = t ()
      return setmetatable ( function () return t1, i+1 end, tail_mt )
    end
  end
end
```

With __index and __newindex metamethods, you can write code such as f[2]=f[1]+1.

Although this (untested) code doesn't endlessly create one-off metatables, it is probably less efficient than prapin's, since it will be calling thunks (0-ary functions) to get at their contents.  But if you might be interested in extending the functionality, say by having more general views on the sequence, I think this is a bit more flexible.